# IIS on Windows XP

Tags: iis, vbscript, windows-xp

Is it possible to run more than one website on IIS 5.1 (Windows XP)?

I'm able to create multiple websites through adminscripts in IIS, but only one website can be active at a time.

Is there is any workaround, trick, or script for this limitation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can only have one active at any one time, but see [this link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000329.html) ([now at](https://blog.codinghorror.com/uncrippling-windows-xps-iis-51/)) by Jeff for more info on how to uncripple IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Port No for each website you created, By default you get port no 80. But here if you dont have Host Headers for the Application then you have to create Each website with each port no like 80, 8080, 8081...etc and try.